# Is there a way to use and ignore blocks of code, caused by events during runtime?

Tags: design, c++, compiler, source-code

I'm working in C++14 and trying to figure out a way to put two classes (with the same name) inside the same header file. In this scenario one class would always be ignored as a result of something happening in main.cpp during runtime. Here's an example of this header file:

```
// First class:
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
private:
    int var;
};

foo::foo()
{
    var = 1;
}

// Second class:
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
private:
    int var;
};

foo::foo()
{
    var = 2;
}
```

So let's say during runtime the user entered "1". Then the first definition of class foo would be used, and the compiler would ignore the second class. But then if the user enters "2", the first class is ignored and the second class is used.

I know it's ugly, but in my specific case it saves a ton of work.

Comment: You cannot do this.  You need to learn about inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: Either you need a time machine in order for the runtime to affect the compilation process or you are not being clear what you exactly want to do.

Comment: @Peter M Do you mean a logical or bitwise or?

Comment: I meant a Logical Or

Comment: @Peter M But if I'm clever enough to make a time machine wouldn't it follow that I'm clear on exactly what I'm doing?

Comment: If you're clever enough to make a time machine, then you don't need to be asking this on here as you already known that I would dispute that your question was clear and question your confusion of runtime and compilation processes.  Unless of course you are using a fancy quantum computer with chronotronic modules.  In which case why are you confusing us technological cavemen? Or do you enjoy slumming it in the past and lording over us with you highfalutin future talk?

Comment: @Peter M Unless I went back in time and knew we would be having this argument. Which gives me a reason to make this post, not because I'm unclear on compilation processes but because I was leading up to this very moment. Thus, it is possible I can time travel and be clear on compilation processes, and still make this post.

Comment: I guess what you are really after is "foo" as an abstract base class of two other classes "foo1" and "foo2", and a factory method which creates either objects of type "foo1" or "foo2", which are then used as "foo" objects throughout the rest of the program. This approach has a name, it is called [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: @Doc Brown Yes, I've decided to do that. The base class could even be mostly empty, except for the public methods I need to call from main.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Technically, it's possible

You can give two different classes the same name, by putting each class in separate namespaces:

```
namespace space_1 {
    class foo { ... }; 
}  

namespace space_2 {
    class foo { ... }; 
}
```

This defines two different and unrelated classes: `space_1::foo` and `space_2::foo`.

You may then define at compile time which namespace to use in the using context (in `main()`, or in a configuration header):

```
int main() {
    using namespace space_1; 
    foo a; 
}
```

If you want to choose either the one or the other at run time, you'll have to either use explicit scope resolution, or use the class and the defined object in a limited scope using a namespace:

```
if (a) {
    using namespace space_1; 
    foo f; 
    // do smething with f HERE 
}
else {
    using namespace space_2; 
    foo f; 
    // do something else with f HERE
}
```

#### But does it make sense ?

Using different namespaces for classes with the same name is typically used for managing compile-time library dependencies, for example:

- avoiding name conflicts between different components.
- new version of a library with a different interface.
- choice of alternative libraries (e.g. `boost::xxx` vs. `std::xxx`).

It is a very bad idea to use this construct for a different purpose, such as choosing the class implementations at runtime.

#### Is there a better design ?

If you have a class with a well defined API, but need to cope with different variants/implementations at run time, you may consider polymorphism:

- Make `foo` an abstract base class, and create a derived class for every needed variant.
- Use a [factory](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) to instantiate the objects with the right derived class.

Alternatively, you may redesign your foo class, so that it requires a parameter in the constructor (i.e. the initial value of var in your case) or inject a [strategy](https://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) in the constructor.

Comment: I was under the impression that #define is only typed once at the start of a program. There's a way to use #define on two namespaces throughout a program to switch back and forth between their respective classes?

Comment: I'm actually already doing what you coded (using different namespaces for my classes). It's worked well so far since I only ever use two classes at the same time. Now though I want to use 10+ of these classes, which would require 10 different namespaces. That would mean I have 10 different kinds of pointers/objects, requiring 10 different (essentially identical) functions for operating on each kind of pointer. I was hoping to get around this somehow.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance in my example, enclosing the classes within two different namespaces will result in two (potentially completely) different classes `space_1::foo` and `space_2::foo`.  The using clause is just a shortcut to choose a default prefix at compile time.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance If you have 10 different classes, the namespace trick is definitely not the way to go (see third bullet of the "bear in mind").  You're better of using an abstract class with a couple of variations.  Alternatively, you may also consider having only one class, but inject some strategy at construction of the objet.

Comment: Yeah an abstract class is probably the best way to go, not sure why I didn't give it much thought. It would allow me to write functions acting on the same type for all 10 different objects. Thx!

Comment: The question was *"one class would always be ignored as a result of something happening in main.cpp during runtime"* - but what you are showing above is a compile time decision, not a runtime decision. So either OP (in accepting your answer) did not understand what they were asking for, or they did not understand what your answer is about, or I did not understand something here.

Comment: @DocBrown If you read the second part of my answer and specially the last bullet, and the exchange of comments with OP, you'll find out that we understood mutually very well.  The conclusion is that one class with several definitions was not a good idea and abstract class would be a far better solution.

Comment: @Christophe: I think it would be better if you edit your answer in a way other readers are not forced to scan through all the comments to understand why you did not answer the literal question, as it is written.

Comment: @DocBrown that's a good advice ! I'd prefer to avoid that people misunderstand namespace as alternative for polymorphism.  I've edited and clarified.